# Customer login changes shipping method

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, quote, onestepcheckout

We've made a custom implementation for Magento 1.9.2.2 in which a customer can select his preferred shipping method in the cart. The form for the implementation in the cart looks like this `<form id="co-shipping-method-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimateUpdatePost') ?>">` and then hits:

```
    {
        $code = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('estimate_method');
        if (!empty($code)) {
            $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($code)/*->collectTotals()*/->save();
        }
        $this->_goBack();
    }
```

So far so good I think.

We're using Idev's OneStepCheckout where customers can login during the checkout. When people login during the checkout the preferred shipping method selected in the cart is changed. It looks like something happens with the quote upon login. When echoing the shippingmethods `$code` before the login we get the right value. But after logging in the value changes.

Is it possible the quote isn't being merged properly upon login? I can't seem to find the solution. Maybe some out here has the proper answer. Please feel free to ask any questions regarding this post. Maybe I can supply the post with more information if needed.

Thanks in advance.

I.J.